# Ruby TweetStream Locations Feature not working

Tags: ruby, streaming, twitter

I'm currently accessing the Ruby TweetStream just fine in regards to the "filter" method; however, whenever I try to limit any of the streaming content to a bounding box (which I know works), it just ignores the code or doesn't run at all.

Here's some of my code:

```
TweetStream.configure do |config|
  config.username    = 'USERNAME'
  config.password    = 'PASSWORD'
  config.auth_method = :basic
end

TweetStream::Client.new.filter({:locations => '-80.29,32.57,-79.56,33.09', :track => ["Bob Loblaw"]}) do |tweet|
  p tweet.inspect
end
```

I've also tried the "locations" method:

```
TweetStream::Client.new.filter({:track => ["Bob Loblaw"]}).locations('-80.29,32.57,-79.56,33.09') do |tweet|
  p tweet.inspect
end
```

I've also tried locations(['-80.29,32.57,-79.56,33.09']) and locations(['-80.29,32.57','-79.56,33.09']).

Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TweetStream::Client.new.locations(-80.29,32.57,-79.56,33.09) do |tweet|
  p tweet.inspect
end
```

Or some variation of that.